# Rewrite sentences from first person to third person and vice versa using python packages

Tags: text, url-rewriting, nlp, spacy, grammar

Are there any packages in python that can rewrite large content from Person's point of view i.e first person to third person and Third person to First person

> I ate apple yesterday
> He ate apple yesterday

I have tried to replace the pronouns with relevant pronouns using spacy Language packages and using if condition. is there a simpler way